# RESTful API newbie question about error 400

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

The question is following:

I am having very simple POST method on the server side:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("//api/loggeduser")]
public void Post([FromBody] LoggedUser loggedUser)
```

I am trying to call it from the client side:

```
var loggedUser = new LoggedUser
{
    UserName = userName,
    Logged = true
};

 var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(loggedUser);
 HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();
 HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(json);
 response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("https://localhost:44311/api/loggeduser", httpContent);
```

And I always getting error 400. What I am doing wrong? Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you have two slashes in the beginning of the Route? (`[Route("//api/loggeduser")]`)

Comment: Because I am trying whatever I see in the Internet because I am technically stuck. With one slash result is the same.

Comment: Wait, weren't you supposed to properly configure `HttpClient` with the appropriate `json` content type `Accept` header? I seem to recall you had to. That would explain why `GET` requests work just fine, as I'm guessing you're passing parameters in from the query string, which doesn't involve JSON at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it might work if you tell the StringContent which encoding and content type it should use, like this:

`HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");`

Answer (score 2):

You have an invalid syntax. Whatever information you're attempting to send it is not formatted in a way that the server is willing to accept. You need to check the parameters and make sure you have it written in the correct syntax.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Is there any way to check what exactly is wrong? I am getting [HttpGet] data without any problem.

Comment: Is the `LoggedUser` class the same in the client and server?

Comment: Yes it is the same class (copypasted from server code to client code)

Comment: You should have some sort of documentation as to what parameters you can send to the URL. If no documentation, whoever admins the website should be able to help you with that. If you feel you have a pretty good idea for what you need to send it, you'll need to check and make sure you're encoding it correctly. As @ShamPooSham suggested,  maybe try and explicitly declare UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to let `content-type` to be `application/json`.

```
StringContent content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```